# How do I move TODO entries to the bottom of a task list?

Tags: org-mode

That is, how do I change this task list

```
* TODO A
* DONE B
* TODO C
* DONE D
* TODO E
```

into the following one?

```
* DONE B
* DONE D
* TODO A
* TODO C
* TODO E
```

Comment: Are you interested in just manual manipulation, instead of programmatic?  http://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-editing.html  If you are interested in programmatic, then your proposed finished product looks random (absent you providing more explanation as to how it is that you arrived at that particular order).

Comment: I think you can do something similar with Org sorting functions, i.e. by calling `C-c ^` on selected headings.

Comment: The following link contains an advanced programmatic sorting example:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22232709/2112489

Comment: @lawlist: Sorry the sorting order wasn't clear (I didn't realize it would look random): it's just a stable sort by todo state: DONE entries are moved to the beginning, and TODO ones to the end.

Comment: Ah . . . I see now -- thank you.  I normally sort 4 times for the majority of entries (?a ?o ?p ?t) using `org-sort-entries` -- erikstokes has already cited the interactive command that uses `org-sort-entries`.  It operates on regions or on everything under a main heading.  It also takes an optional custom function for special sorts.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `org-sort` to sort by todo state, or any thing else.  By default it's bound to `C-c ^`;  it will ask you what you want to sort by.  Choose `O` to sort by todo state, reversed (`o` will put `TODO` at the top).